# Certificate access error during Terraform plan

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I think I'm in a bit of a chicken and egg situation, where I need to declare a certificate resource for our application gateway, but our app principal that runs Terraform in our pipeline doesn't have permissions until after applying is complete. Basically, the service principal cannot access certificates during planning, so planning never completes, and apply can't run because there is no plan file output.

Is there any way around this besides manually configuring permissions in the UI?

The access policy *does include "Get" permissions for the certificate*

Key Vault

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "web" {
  name                = lower(format("az-kv-web-%s-%s-%s", var.instance.environment, var.instance.az-region, var.instance.serial))
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.web.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.web.name

  sku_name = var.instance.key-vault.sku-name

  # Azure AD tenant
  tenant_id = var.instance.aad-tenant-id

  dynamic "access_policy" {
    for_each = var.instance.key-vault.access

    content {
      tenant_id               = var.instance.aad-tenant-id
      object_id               = access_policy.value.object-id

      certificate_permissions = access_policy.value.cert-permissions
      key_permissions         = access_policy.value.key-permissions
      secret_permissions      = access_policy.value.secret-permissions
      storage_permissions     = access_policy.value.storage-permissions
    }
  }
}
```

Certificate

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "gateway" {
  name = var.gateway.certificate-name

  key_vault_id = var.key-vault.id
}
```

Error

```
╷
│ Error: reading Key Vault Certificate: keyvault.BaseClient#GetCertificate: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="The user, group or application 'appid=***;oid=***;numgroups=3;iss=https://sts.windows.net/***/' does not have certificates get permission on key vault 'az-kv-web-dev-eastus-001;location=eastus'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287" InnerError={"code":"ForbiddenByPolicy"}
│ 
│   with module.web["001"].module.app-gateway.data.azurerm_key_vault_certificate.gateway,
│   on modules\app-gateway\main.tf line 123, in data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "gateway":
│  123: data "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "gateway" {
│ 
╵
```

Comment: What is the complete error message

Comment: @kavyaS apologies, didn't even cross my mind. Updated

Comment: try to give the service principal  , `Get` access from keyvault access policies..

Comment: How are you creating the certificate in your Keyvault? Uploading it or generating it inside the Keyvault?

Answer (score 1):

To create certificate and access it  , I used below code:

gave terraform plan and `terraform apply`

**code:**

```
data "azurerm_subscription" "current" {}

resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  display_name     = "newexample"
 // identifier_uris  = ["https://kavyaexample.com"]
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADMultipleOrgs"

  api {
    mapped_claims_enabled          = true
    requested_access_token_version = 2

    oauth2_permission_scope {
      admin_consent_description  = "Allow the application to access example on behalf of the signed-in user."
      admin_consent_display_name = "Access example"
      enabled                    = true
      id                         = "96183846-204b-4b43-82e1-5d2222eb4b9b"
      type                       = "User"
      user_consent_description   = "Allow the application to access example on your behalf."
      user_consent_display_name  = "Access example"
      value                      = "user_impersonation"
    }

    oauth2_permission_scope {
      admin_consent_description  = "Administer the example application"
      admin_consent_display_name = "Administer"
      enabled                    = true
      id                         = "be98fa3e-ab5b-4b11-83d9-04ba2b7946bc"
      type                       = "Admin"
      value                      = "administer"
    }
  }

  app_role {
    allowed_member_types = ["User", "Application"]
    description          = "Admins can manage roles and perform all task actions"
    display_name         = "Admin"
    enabled              = true
    id                   = "1b19509b-32b1-4e9f-b71d-4992aa991967"
    value                = "admin"
  }

  app_role {
    allowed_member_types = ["User"]
    description          = "ReadOnly roles have limited query access"
    display_name         = "ReadOnly"
    enabled              = true
    id                   = "497406e4-012a-4267-bf18-45a1cb148a01"
    value                = "User"
  }

  feature_tags {
    enterprise = true
    gallery    = true
  }

  optional_claims {
    access_token {
      name = "myclaim"
    }

    access_token {
      name = "otherclaim"
    }

    id_token {
      name                  = "userclaim"
      source                = "user"
      essential             = true
      additional_properties = ["emit_as_roles"]
    }

    saml2_token {
      name = "samlexample"
    }
  }

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" # Microsoft Graph

    resource_access {
      id   = "df021288-bdef-4463-88db-98f22de89214" # User.Read.All
      type = "Role"
    }

    resource_access {
      id   = "b4e74841-8e56-480b-be8b-910348b18b4c" # User.ReadWrite
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "c5393580-f805-4401-95e8-94b7a6ef2fc2" # Office 365 Management

    resource_access {
      id   = "594c1fb6-4f81-4475-ae41-0c394909246c" # ActivityFeed.Read
      type = "Role"
    }
  }

  web {
    homepage_url  = "https://app.example.net"
    logout_url    = "https://app.example.net/logout"
    redirect_uris = ["https://app.example.net/account"]

    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = true
      id_token_issuance_enabled     = true
    }
  }

  
}

resource "azuread_service_principal" "example" {
  application_id               = azuread_application.example.application_id
  app_role_assignment_required = false
  owners                       = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  
}

/*
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "example" {
  scope              = "/subscriptions/f10a5570-53f3-473f-9c2f-bd0ee87ca71c/resourceGroups/v-sakavya-Mindtree"
  role_definition_id = "b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
  principal_id       = azuread_service_principal.example.object_id

}

*/
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "kavyaexmplkeyvault"
  location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
   object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

   //object_id= azuread_service_principal.example.object_id
    
    certificate_permissions = [
      "Create",
      "Delete",
      "DeleteIssuers",
      "Get",
      "GetIssuers",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "ListIssuers",
      "ManageContacts",
      "ManageIssuers",
      "Purge",
      "SetIssuers",
      "Update",
    ]

    key_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Create",
      "Decrypt",
      "Delete",
      "Encrypt",
      "Get",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Sign",
      "UnwrapKey",
      "Update",
      "Verify",
      "WrapKey",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Delete",
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Set",
    ]
    storage_permissions = [
      "Get","Set"
    ]
  }

  
}



resource "tls_private_key" "example" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}



resource "azurerm_key_vault_certificate" "example" {
  name         = "kavya-cert"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id

  certificate_policy {
    issuer_parameters {
      name = "Self"
    }

    key_properties {
      exportable = true
      key_size   = 2048
      key_type   = "RSA"
      reuse_key  = true
    }

    lifetime_action {
      action {
        action_type = "AutoRenew"
      }

      trigger {
        days_before_expiry = 30
      }
    }

    secret_properties {
      content_type = "application/x-pkcs12"
    }

    x509_certificate_properties {
      # Server Authentication = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
      # Client Authentication = 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2
      extended_key_usage = ["1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1"]

      key_usage = [
        "cRLSign",
        "dataEncipherment",
        "digitalSignature",
        "keyAgreement",
        "keyCertSign",
        "keyEncipherment",
      ]

      subject_alternative_names {
        dns_names = ["internal.contoso.com", "domain.hello.world"]
      }

      subject            = "CN=hello-world"
      validity_in_months = 12
    }
  }
}



resource "azuread_application_certificate" "example" {
  application_object_id = azuread_application.example.id
  type                  = "AsymmetricX509Cert"
  encoding              = "hex"
  value                 = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.certificate_data
  //end_date              = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.certificate_attribute[0].expires
  //start_date            = azurerm_key_vault_certificate.example.certificate_attribute[0].not_before
}
```

[image]

As the service principal got the certificate get, list , create and delete access privileges.

[image]

But when I tried removing this access policy to the service principal , I got similar error

```
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "kavyaexmplkeyvault"
  location                    = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
  sku_name = "standard"

  access_policy {
    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  // object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

   object_id= azuread_service_principal.example.object_id
    
    certificate_permissions = [
      "Create",
      "Delete",
      "DeleteIssuers",
      "Get",
      "GetIssuers",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "ListIssuers",
      "ManageContacts",
      "ManageIssuers",
      "Purge",
      "SetIssuers",
      "Update",
    ]

    key_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Create",
      "Decrypt",
      "Delete",
      "Encrypt",
      "Get",
      "Import",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Sign",
      "UnwrapKey",
      "Update",
      "Verify",
      "WrapKey",
    ]

    secret_permissions = [
      "Backup",
      "Delete",
      "Get",
      "List",
      "Purge",
      "Recover",
      "Restore",
      "Set",
    ]
    storage_permissions = [
      "Get","Set"
    ]
  }

  
}
```

**Error:**

`Status=403 Code="Forbidden" Message="The user, group or application 'appid=***;oid=***;numgroups=3;iss=https://sts.windows.net/***/' does not have certificates get permission on key vault`

---

[image]

---

- Then I tried to create it again with the servicepricipal giving access policies .
  But still faced same error .
- Then I destroyed the files but no change as it is stored in the backend and the certificate privileges cant be changes unless we have access.

---

[image]

- Instead I have changed the keyvault name and certificate name in terraform.
- Deleted the existing certificate in azure ad app.
- And then created and run terraform plan and terraform apply .

[image]

---

Direct terraform apply also worked with the above starting code.

And it created the service principal access policies.

[image]

**Certificate retrieved in azure ad application.**

[image]

Comment: this looks like it would work, but we're using a certificate from GoDaddy, not Microsoft generated

Comment: Have you tried giving new keyvault name,certificate name and then tried applying with access policies given to your current object , data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id  and required user or admin role to azure ad user as in code.

Comment: Make sure GoDaddy API key has the necessary permissions to access the certificate and recheck the certificate configuration